# return publishingcredentials from Azure as json output

Tags: json, azure

**Edit: I thought I'd tried this before posting, but I guess not - the solution was:

`"listPublishingUsername": {
      "value": "[list(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/config', variables('websiteName'), 'publishingcredentials'), '2016-08-01').properties.publishingUserName]",
      "type": "string"
    },`

```
"listPublishingPassword": {
  "value": "[list(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/config', variables('websiteName'), 'publishingcredentials'), '2016-08-01').properties.publishingPassword]",
  "type": "string"
}
```

I'm trying to get the publishingUsername/publishingPassword nested values from an Azure JSON deployment.

With:

```
  "outputs": {
"listPublishingCredentials": {
  "value": "[list(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/config', parameters('sites_testdsfsdfsfsfs_name'), 'publishingcredentials'), '2014-06-01')]",
  "type": "object"
```

I'm able to get all values that I can see in the resource portal

if I suffix it with .parameters I'm able to get down a level to just the parameters, however if I try parameters.publishingPassword (which would be the nested value based on the resource view) it returns an error

```
"code": "DeploymentOutputEvaluationFailed",
  "target": "listPublishingCredentials",
  "message": "The template output 'listPublishingCredentials' is not valid: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list..""
```

Alternatively is there any documentation that explains what parameters/syntax is valid for resources like Microsoft.Web/sites/config?

edit:

```
  "outputs": {
"listPublishingCredentials": {
  "value": "[list(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/config', parameters('sites_testdsfsdfsfsfs_name'), 'publishingcredentials'), '2016-08-01').properties]",
  "type": "object"
}
```

works

```
  "outputs": {
"listPublishingCredentials": {
  "value": "[list(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/config', parameters('sites_testdsfsdfsfsfs_name'), 'publishingcredentials'), '2016-08-01').properties.publishingPassword]",
  "type": "object"
}
```

doesn't

Comment: Show the code for .publishing password that is not working.

Comment: @Mitul, I've edited into the original comment since reply formatting is troublesome

Answer (score 2):

```
"listPublishingUsername": {
  "value": "[list(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/config', variables('websiteName'), 'publishingcredentials'), '2016-08-01').properties.publishingUserName]",
  "type": "string"
},

"listPublishingPassword": {
  "value": "[list(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/config', variables('websiteName'), 'publishingcredentials'), '2016-08-01').properties.publishingPassword]",
  "type": "string"
}
```